Why goroutine delay sometimes? Is it caused by GC? How do I profile time cost?
The problem is I get
about >1ms delay when I create one hundred/thousand gorountine.
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ { // or use 1000
        go func() { testWaitRoutine() }()
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}

func testWaitRoutine() {
    channl := make(chan int, 1)

    go func() {
        channl <- time.Now().Nanosecond()
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        channl <- time.Now().Nanosecond()
    }()

    _, secondTime := <-channl, <-channl
    nowTime := time.Now().Nanosecond()
    delay := nowTime - secondTime
    println(delay)
}

OUTPUT show there are very few result count of microseconds and milliseconds delay, such as:
...
3000
338000
2000
...
1000
1000
72000
1000
...
2000
2000
1185000
1000
1000
...

Hardware: Both of MBP(2017) and Windows 10 have this phenomenon.
[Question]
Why will gorountine give a larger delay result sometimes than a stable delay number? What's the underlay implementation causing?

Works as specified: No guarantees are made regarding the setup time of a goroutine nor that a read from a channel is instantaneous. In other words: none of your implementations should ever rely on any timing regarding read operations from channels or setup times of goroutines.

hi, @MarkusWMahlberg, I'm understand it's beyond real implement. Do you have any recommand resource for current "executing independently in a new goroutine" implement explains as docs link said? The point is almost waiting time is small but few of them are large x100 times

Is this a real world Problem for your app?

NO. I'm newbiee to golang want deeply know the underimplement.

@LoranceChen Other than reading the source code? No. My 2 cents? I think you are putting the cart before the horse here. Knowing the spec is hard enough (as evidenced), knowing the implementation details for every target platform is a whole different thin.

You can find the implementation for channels here in chan.go and goroutines here in proc.go. Good luck!

Remove print will get a large performance increase even though some delay here.
only 200~300 counts over 3000ns
func main() {
    stat := [10000]int{}
    p := &stat
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        go func() {
            testWaitRoutine(p, i)
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    // time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    count := 0

    for i, v := range p {
        if v > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("i: %d, value: %d\n", i, v)
            count++
        }
    }

    println("count: ", count)
}

func testWaitRoutine(stats *[10000]int, index int) {
    channl := make(chan int, 2)

    go func() {
        channl <- time.Now().Nanosecond()
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        channl <- time.Now().Nanosecond()
    }()

    _, secondTime := <-channl, <-channl
    nowTime := time.Now().Nanosecond()
    rst2 := nowTime - secondTime

    if rst2 > 3_000 {
        // fmt.Println(rst2)
        (*stats)[index] = rst2
    } else {
    }

}


Yes, printing is slow because there needs to be a lock around the stdout stream.
